# How to implement GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql

here's my sql statement

```
SELECT ut.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ut.bet_group_id)
FROM users_transaction AS ut
WHERE ut.user_id = 3
GROUP BY ut.user_id
ORDER BY ut.id DESC;
```

my is goal is to `group_concat` the `bet_group_id` by `user_id`, but when i execute my query above, i get this following error `Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'p2p_trade.ut.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

and here's my sample table

```
  id   user_id   bet_group_id 
   1      3         2            
   2      3         1            
   3      3         2           
   4      3         null
```

expected output will be

```
  id   user_id   bet_group_id  type_id
   1      3         2,2         
   2      3         1           
   4      3         null
```

Comment: What is the expected output you want to see here?

Comment: i don't understand the logic to merge id 1,3 to 1 and type_id 1,3 to 1

Comment: @Hirumina i already remove the `type_id`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i already add the expected ouput

Comment: Your error message has backticks, but the query doesn't. That error message must be for a different query. Show the real query.

Comment: `GROUP BY` has to be before `ORDER BY`

Comment: Edit the question, the backticks are treated as markdown in the comment.

Comment: Describe grouping logic. Now it looks like grouping by `(user_id, bet_group_id)` with taking minimal `id` and `type_id` values for a group. And your `ORDER BY ut.id DESC` contradicts desired output where ordering direction is ASC.

Comment: You have no `deleted_at` column in the sample table.

Comment: @Barmar i didn't include the deleted_at, it's not important.

Comment: Your expected output has multiple rows for the same `user_id`. That's not possible with `GROUP BY user_id`.

Comment: When I run your query I get a syntax error near `GROUP BY` because you have the clauses in the wrong order.

Comment: If it's not important, don't put it in the query -- it causes an error when I try to run your query at sqlfiddle with the sample data.

Comment: @Barmar so what should i do?, any opinion?

Comment: Put `GROUP BY` before `ORDER BY`, then you won't get a syntax error.

Comment: @Barmar wait ill try

Comment: You still haven't edited the question to show the query that actually caused that error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is because `GROUP BY` has to be before `ORDER BY`, although the error message is not the same as the one you show (it should say `near "GROUP BY"`).

In order to get a separate row for each `bet_group_id`, you need to incluide that column in the `GROUP BY` clause.

And to get the rows in the order you want, don't use `DESC`.

```
SELECT ut.*, GROUP_CONCAT(ut.bet_group_id)
FROM users_transaction AS ut
WHERE ut.user_id = 3
GROUP BY ut.user_id, ut.bet_group_id
ORDER BY ut.id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72e9f9/5)

Comment: i think there's no wrong with this query, it's now producing diff error.

Comment: Are you getting an error about `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115174/error-related-to-only-full-group-by-when-executing-a-query-in-mysql